# Remove rows from dataframe by name from a table

Tags: r, dataframe, rows

I must remove a lot of rows from my dataframe, named countdata. Each row corresponds to a gene, each column to a patient (sample). To do so, I have a list of 7667 genes in format .ids that I loaded in R this way.

```
remove <- read.table("unwanted.ensembl.gene.ids", 
header=F, check.names=F)
```

Here's what the heads of countdata and remove look like.

```
> head(countdata[,1:5])
             gene SRR1790991 SRR1790997 SRR1790999 SRR1791001
1 ENSG00000000003          5         32         10         33
2 ENSG00000000005          0          0          0          0
3 ENSG00000000419       2934       3075       2124        944
4 ENSG00000000457        686        670        630        735
5 ENSG00000000460        543        177       1986        824
6 ENSG00000000938        807        534        116         98

> head(remove)
           V1
1 ENSG00000130600
2 ENSG00000163597
3 ENSG00000166917
4 ENSG00000174365
5 ENSG00000175061
6 ENSG00000186594
```

So, I have tried to drop all the rows listed in "remove" with the following code:

```
countdata <- countdata[!rownames(countdata) %in% remove,]
```

However, when I compare the nrow() of countdata before and after the command, the number of rows remains the same.

I have also unsuccessfully tried:

```
countdata <- countdata[!(row.names(countdata) %in% remove),]
countdata <- countdata[!row.names(countdata) %in% remove,]
countdata <- countdata[!row.names(countdata) %in% remove$V1,]
countdata = countdata[!rownames(countdata) %in% remove[,1],]
```

I guess I am having trouble because I am not dealing correctly with my table "remove". Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Looks like you have a column `gene` in 'countdata' instead of `rownames` i.e.  have you tried `countdata[!countdata$gene %in% remove$V1,]`

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much!